# roswtf pythonpath

Tags: ros, roswtf, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I run roswtf to check if everything is fine with my `ROS-noetic`, but I failed to interpret this error right. So could somebody explain why these two paths seemed to be wrong or setted wrong? On ROS Answers I don't see a question like this and also on github

```
ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/home/pkatsoulakos/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/bin/python3:/usr/bin/python] point to a directory: 
 * /usr/bin/python3
 * /usr/bin/python
```

Thanks for helping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399771/roswtf-pythonpath/) by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2022-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is supposed to contain a list of paths (or: directories).

From [the official documentation on PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (emphasis mine):

> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s `PATH`: **one or more directory pathnames** separated by `os.pathsep` (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.
>
> In addition to normal directories, individual `PYTHONPATH` entries may refer to zipfiles containing pure Python modules (in either source or compiled form). Extension modules cannot be imported from zipfiles.

As you can read: plain files are not supposed to be listed in this environment variable.

Despite its name, it's *not* "the path to the python executable".

In your case, you have:

- `/home/pkatsoulakos/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages`
- `/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages`
- `/usr/bin/python3`
- `/usr/bin/python`

It's very likely `/usr/bin/python3` (and `/usr/bin/python`) are not paths, but files.

Hence the complaint from `roswtf`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-27**:
Note that this is not a "ROS problem". `PYTHONPATH` is part of the regular Python runtime configuration infrastructure.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-27**:
Hey thanks for the quick response,

yes you're right, these two are files not folders, so I guess I can remove them from my PYTHONPATH without doubt?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-27**:
I can't say.

Those two entries don't make sense to me, but I also don't know how / why they ended up on your `PYTHONPATH` in the first place.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-28**:
so I just uncomment in my `bashrc` file the 2 lines with `/usr/bin/python3` and `usr/bin/python`. Dont remember why I've done this, but now it seems to be ok. Could be marked as answered

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-28**:\

> Could be marked as answered

that would be something you could/should do.

Tick the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer.